# How do I insert a 'datetime.now' when it's formatted like 'date(18, 8, 2019)?

Tags: python, datetime

So, I'm trying to make a code that calculates when you'll reach your next birth milestones in days ("You'll turn 5000 days in 1004 more days on September 19, 2084").

```py
from datetime import date
d0 = date(2008, 9, 26)
d1 = date(2008, 9, 26)
delta = d1 - d0
print("delta.days")
```

I want to insert `datetime.now` to `d0 = date(2008, 9, 26)` so it's something like `d0 = datetime.now` but that (and other variations like `d0 = date(datetime.now())`) doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I meant I wanted the variable d0 to represent today's date. I know datetime.now is the variable for today's date but it doesn't fit in the parameter.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Could you please elaborate on `I want to insert datetime.now to d0 = date(2008, 9, 26) so it's something like d0 = datetime.now`? This part of the question is not very clear. Also, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks! I meant I wanted the variable d0 to represent today's date. I know ```datetime.now``` is the variable for today's date but it doesn't fit in the parameter. Does that make it more understandable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`datetime.now`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#available-types) returns a DateTime - unsurprising given its name.

You want a Date.

The documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#available-types) shows that you can get the date portion of a datetime by using the `date` attribute.

So you probably want something like this:

```
d0 = datetime.now().date
```

Comment: When I use the code you used above, it shows me an error in the output.

```NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined```

Comment: Well I guess you have to learn basic python stuff. You have to import library before using it. To use datetime library `import datetime`.

Comment: Pretty much what Deb said. I assumed you already had that library imported, because you mentioned using `datetime.now` in your question.

Comment: I do have that library imported. This is my exact code ```from datetime import date

d0 = datetime.now()
d1 = date(2008, 9, 26)
delta = d1 - d0
print(delta.days)```. When I run it, it says that 'datetime' is not defined.

Comment: You have `date` imported from the `datetime` module. You need `datetime` from the `datetime` module - so you'd be looking at something like `from datetime import date, datetime`.